# AWStats multiple columns in extra section

Tags: regex, perl, awstats

I have an AWStats running and the reports are built from IIS logfiles. 
I have an extra section to view all the actions of the executed perlscripts on the site.

The config looks like this:

```
ExtraSectionName1="Actions"
ExtraSectionCodeFilter1="200 304"
ExtraSectionCondition1="URL,\/cgi\-bin\/.+\.pl"
ExtraSectionFirstColumnTitle1="Action"
ExtraSectionFirstColumnValues1="QUERY_STRING,action=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)"
ExtraSectionFirstColumnFormat1="%s"
ExtraSectionStatTypes1=HPB
ExtraSectionAddAverageRow1=0
ExtraSectionAddSumRow1=1
MaxNbOfExtra1=20
MinHitExtra1=1
```

The output looks like this:

```
Action    Pages    Hits
foo       1234     1234
bar       5678     5678
```

But there are some actions with the same name in different perl scripts. 
I would need this:

```
Script    Action    Pages    Hits
foo.pl    foo       1234     1234
bar.pl    foo       1234     1234
foo.pl    bar       5678     5678
bar.pl    bar       5678     5678
```

Does anyone know how to create such a report?

**EDIT:**

I did some more research and all forum posts I've found say that it is not possible to have two columns in an extra section without hacking in `awstats.pl`

Now I am trying to put it into one column using `URLWITHQUERY` to output someting like this:

```
Action                  Pages    Hits
foo.pl?action=foo       1234     1234
foo.pl?action=bar       1234     1234
bar.pl?action=foo       5678     5678
...
```

The new problem is that the query has more parameters than action, which are unordered.
I tried this

```
ExtraSectionFirstColumnValues1="URLWITHQUERY,([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.pl\?).*(action=[a-zA-Z0-9]+)"
```

but AWStats only gets the value from the first bracket pair and ignores the rest. I think it internally works with `$1` provided by the perl regex 'magic'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution.

`awstats.pl` fetches the data for the specified extra sections in `line 19664 - 19750`

This is my modification:

```
# Line 19693 - 19701 in awstats.pl (AWStats version 7 Revision 1.971)
elsif ( $rowkeytype eq 'URLWITHQUERY' ) {
    if ( "$urlwithnoquery$tokenquery$standalonequery" =~
        /$rowkeytypeval/ )
    {
        $rowkeyval = "$1$2"; # I simply added a $2 for the second capture group
        $rowkeyok  = 1;
        last;
    }
}
```

This will get the first and the second capture group specified in the ExtraSectionFirstColumnValuesX regex.

Example:

`ExtraSectionFirstColumnValues1="URLWITHQUERY,([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.pl\?).*(action=[a-zA-Z0-9]+)"`

Needless to say that you need to add a `$3 $4 $5 ...` if you need more groups.

Answer (score 0):

maybe?

```
ExtraSectionFirstColumnTitle1="Script"
ExtraSectionFirstColumnValues1="URL,\/cgi\-bin\/(.+\.pl)`enter code here`"
ExtraSectionFirstColumnFormat1="%s"

ExtraSectionFirstColumnTitle2="Action"
ExtraSectionFirstColumnValues2="QUERY_STRING,action=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)"
ExtraSectionFirstColumnFormat2="%s"
```

Comment: Doesn't that make a new section? (Is this sentence correct verbalized? Please correct me if I am wrong...) but I'll give it a try on monday.

Comment: There was no error. It compiled the logs and showed the script column. The action column was ignored.